# XPath query returns null

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

As you see in the picture an item has subitems which are `<th>` and `<td>`. When I query item to get `<td>`, it returns null. Here is the code: `item.SelectSingleNode("td")`
Shouldn't it get td node?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXu7W.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `<td>` isn't direct child of current `item`. To select descendant that isn't direct child you can use double slashes (`//`) :

```
item.SelectSingleNode(".//td")
```

And if I see it correctly, `<td>` is child of `<th>`, so you can also do this way :

```
item.SelectSingleNode("th/td")
```

Comment: In the source of the html td is not child of th. But in watch window it shows td inside th. Interesting.